# Need a regex to match a word which begins with @ symbol

Tags: regex

Let's say I was looking for the word `hello`, I would use a regex of:

```
/\bhello\b/
```

And, of course, that works great.  But what I really need to match is `@hello`.  And I have been unable to come up with a regex to make that work.  The closest thing that I've found is:

```
/[@]hello\b/
```

Close but not perfect.

The problem is that is also matches stuff like "x@hello".  I've been unable to get that left boundary defined correctly.

Comment: Will the left boundary always be at the beginning of the line?  If so, prefix the RE with `^`.  What other patterns are you trying to avoid matching, and what language are you writing this in?  Different regex parsers follow different "rules".

Comment: Good question - the target, "@hello", can appear anywhere in a string.  Beginning, end, or middle...  I am writing the regex in java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `\B` before `@` for this:

```
/\B@hello\b/
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fO2eW0/1)

`\B` asserts position where `\b` doesn't match.

---

**EDIT:** If requirement is to match `@hello` only if it is preceded by whitespace or line start then use:

```
(?<=\s|^)@hello\b
```

Comment: [I do not think this is specific enough](http://www.regexr.com/3boq7), as this also matches `.@hello` and anything else that's not a word character before the `@`.

Comment: Hmm in that case it might be `(?<=\s|^)@hello\b` but I like to know OP's requirements for this.

Comment: The /\B@hello\b/ meets my needs.  Niels, you are right that it matches .@hello, but only the @hello portion are in the match - that's what I want.  Likewise, this solution would not match x@hello - which is what I also want.  Sorry if I was not clear - thank you both for helping.  I've learned something and saved a lot of time.

Answer (score 2):

You want to match all instances where the string you define is either preceded by whitespace, or the beginning of the string, and ends at a word boundary.

The correct regex is therefore:

```
([\s]|^)(@hello)\b
```

[Proof at regexr](http://www.regexr.com/3boq4).

Comment: Super close - but this solution includes the preceding whitespace in the match.  Would prefer not to have that in the matched result.

Comment: You could just always use the second match, that's what the parentheses are for. The first matching group is just there to group the preceding options.

Comment: Niels - gave a +1 because this helped.  I "accepted" the other solution because it more exactly matched my particular scenario.

Answer (score 0):

```
function convertHashtags ($str)
{
$regex="/@+([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/";
$str=preg_replace($regex, '<a href="$1">$0</a>', $str);
return $str;
}

echo convertHashtags("hello @stackoverflow kal");
```